# Duplicate output of a program

Tags: linux

Sometimes you want to have the output in a special file. So you can do something like this:

```
ls > test.txt
```

But sometimes I want to have the output also on my command line, for example when the program takes additional input and you want to see what the program wants you to input.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `tee`:

`ls | tee test.txt`